# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

before adding the map function i was getting the state
[image]

after adding map function i get.

[image]

I am not able to pinpoint the location of the problem.saw many posts on stackoverflow but none solved my probem

```
import React,{Fragment,useEffect} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import PostItem from './PostItem'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getPosts} from '../../actions/post'
import Spinner from '../layout/spinner'


const Posts = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } })=>{
useEffect(()=>{
    getPosts();
},[getPosts])

return loading ?<Spinner/>:(
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
          <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome to the community
      </p>
      {/* PostForm*/}
      <div className="posts">
           {
               posts.map((post)=>{
                   return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
               })
           }
      </div>

    </Fragment>
)
}


Posts.propTypes={
 getPosts:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 post:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  post:state.post
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getPosts})(Posts)
```

Comment: first console your posts to check that you r getting values or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check `posts` first before calling map function to prevent calling it before the data being passed to the props. Like this `posts && posts.map(() => {})`

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import PostItem from "./PostItem";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getPosts } from "../../actions/post";
import Spinner from "../layout/spinner";

const Posts = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      getPosts();
    },
    [getPosts]
  );

  return loading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
        <i className="fas fa-user" />Welcome to the community
      </p>
      {/* PostForm*/}
      <div className="posts">
        {posts &&
          posts.map(post => {
            return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />;
          })}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Posts.propTypes = {
  getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});
```

Comment: Its working for me but I am not conviced.I am following a tutorial in udemy and my instructor is not using posts && .how is that working for him ????

Comment: @SwagathShetty maybe he did is the `posts` props is not empty before calling the `<Posts>` component so you don't need to check it anymore inside the component.

For example you `ParentComponent.js` where you use the `<Posts />` component,
`{
post && post.length && <Posts post={post} />
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use condition to check values before mapping to avoid errors.

**1**- {posts?posts.map():null}

**2**- {posts && posts.map()}

```
 <Fragment>
          <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
          <p className="lead">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome to the community
          </p>
          {/* PostForm*/}
          <div className="posts">
               {
                   posts?posts.map((post)=>{
                       return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
                   }):null
               }
          </div>

        </Fragment>
```

or

```
<Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
          <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome to the community
      </p>
      {/* PostForm*/}
      <div className="posts">
           {
               posts && posts.map((post)=>{
                   return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
               })
           }
      </div>

    </Fragment>
```

Comment: It's `posts?.map` by the way. I don't think `posts?posts.map` is valid

Comment: @iamdevlinph it's ternary condition

Comment: Ah my bad. Didn't notice the `: null` at the bottom. I thought you were doing an optional chaining

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the below code.

```
import React,{Fragment,useEffect} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import PostItem from './PostItem'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {getPosts} from '../../actions/post'
import Spinner from '../layout/spinner'


const Posts = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } })=>{
useEffect(()=>{
    getPosts();
},[getPosts])

return loading ?<Spinner/>:(
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
          <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome to the community
      </p>
      {/* PostForm*/}
      {posts.length ? 
      <div className="posts">
           {
               posts.map((post)=>{
                   return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
               })
           }
      </div> : }

    </Fragment>
)
}


Posts.propTypes={
 getPosts:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 post:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  post:state.post
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getPosts})(Posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Posts = ({ getPosts, post: { posts, loading } })=>{
useEffect(()=>{
    getPosts();
},[getPosts])

return loading ?<Spinner/>:(
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Posts</h1>
      <p className="lead">
          <i className="fas fa-user"></i>Welcome to the community
      </p>
      {/* PostForm*/}
      {posts.length ? 
      <div className="posts">
           {
               (posts || []).map((post)=>{
                   return <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
               })
           }
      </div> : }

    </Fragment>
)
}


Posts.propTypes={
 getPosts:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
 post:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({
  post:state.post || [],
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getPosts})(Posts)
```